# Matlab Removing Every Other Element From A 3D Matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a three dimensional matrix from which I would like to remove every other entry from an LxLxL matrix, where L will vary each time I run the code. I have searched through the internet, and I can not seem to find anything helpful. Could someone possibly lend some help.

Thank you

Comment: "Every other entry" in which dimension(s)? And which size do you want the result?

Comment: @LuisMendo Well, the dimensions of the matrix (which are LxLxL) will vary, as they depend on an initial value L that I will change; and I would like to go down the rows and columns and remove every other element, and the repeat this process going up each level. Does that make sense?

Comment: I don't get what you want. Could you give an example of input and output for small L? Specially, which size (shape) should the output have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
M = zeros(L, L, L);
% ...fill M...
M = M(1:2:L, 1:2:L, 1:2:L);
```

Comment: Oh, this is very lovely. Could you possible explain what 1:2:L means/translates to in words? Does it mean run through the numbers 1 to L using a step size of 2?

Comment: Exactly. I suggest to read into the documentation, the colon operator is one of the most important operators in matlab: http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/colon.html